# Vuetify autocomplete component: set value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

We use vuetify autocomplete component https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/autocompletes to display key/value pairs.

When I open page to create new entity all works fine but when when I open page to modify entity where fields must be filled in with saved values then autocomplete field does not display value. 
Here is the example of entity model: 
`{name : "name", legalId : "123", mcc : {id : "1", description : "text"}}`. Items variable has format 
`[{id : "1", description : "text"}, {id : "2", description : "text"}]`

So how it is possible to display "description" property value from `model.mcc.description`?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-form class="mt-5">
      <v-text-field
        v-validate="'required|max:255'"
        v-model="model.name"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('name')"
        :class="inputClass('name')"
        label="Name"
        data-vv-name="name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field
        v-validate="'required|max:255'"
        v-model="model.legalId"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('legalId')"
        :class="inputClass('legalId')"
        label="Legal ID"
        data-vv-name="legalId"
        required
      ></v-text-field>

      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="model.mcc"

        :items="items"
        :loading="isLoading"
        :search-input.sync="searchMccCodes"
        :class="inputClass('mccCode')"
        color="white"
        hide-no-data
        hide-selected
        item-text="description"
        item-value="id"
        label=""
        placeholder="MCC Code"

      ></v-autocomplete>

    </v-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import queries from '../../utils/queries';

export default {
  name: 'MPayMerchantEditor',

  props: ['merchant', 'loading', 'showCancel'],

  components: {},

  data: () => ({
    model: {},
    isLoading: false,
    items: [],
    searchMccCodes: null,
    required: true,
  }),

  computed: {
    isFormValid() {
      return !Object.keys(this.fields)
        .some(key => this.fields[key].invalid);
    },
    isNew() {
      return !this.merchant;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$validator.validateAll()
        .then((isValid) => {
          if (isValid) {
            this.$validator.reset();
            this.$emit('submit', this.model);
          } else {
            this.showValidationErrorMessage();
          }
        });
    },
    cancel() {
      this.$validator.reset();
      this.$emit('cancel', this.model);
    },
    inputClass(name) {
      if (this.fields[name]) {
        const changed = this.fields[name].changed;
        return { 'merchants-editor__input__not-changed': !changed };
      }
      return {};
    },
    storeMerchant() {
      if (this.merchant) {
        Object.keys(this.merchant)
          .forEach((key) => {
            this.model[key] = this.merchant[key];
          });
          this.items.push(this.model.mcc);
        this.$validator.reset();
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.storeMerchant();
  },

  created() {
    merchant);
  },

  watch: {
    merchant() {
      this.storeMerchant();
    },
    searchMccCodes(value) {
      if (!value) {
        return;
      }
      this.isLoading = true;
      axios.get(queries.merchantMccCodes(value))
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data;
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.showError(e);
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },
  },

};
</script>
```

Comment: same issue there and not working with the "return-object" param
i've resolved using v-combobox

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the "selection" scoped slot.

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="model.mcc"

  :items="items"
  :loading="isLoading"
  :search-input.sync="searchMccCodes"
  :class="inputClass('mccCode')"
  color="white"
  hide-no-data
  hide-selected
  item-text="description"
  item-value="id"
  label=""
  placeholder="MCC Code"
  return-object
>
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item.description }}
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

And you should probably add return-object param to the autocomplete tag.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this snippet, you must ensure the property `mcc` is created before the render the component. it should throw an error in console telling you mcc is undefined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="model.mcc"
            :items="items"
            color="white"
            hide-no-data
            hide-selected
            item-text="description"
            item-value="id"
            placeholder="MCC Code"
          />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        model: {mcc: {description: ''}},
        items: [{id:0, description: 'test 1'}, {id:1, description: 'test 2'}]
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `return-object` to your autocomplete tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet worked for me:

```html
  <v-autocomplete
    [...]
    :filter="filter"
    :return-object="true"  
  >
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
      {{ data.item.description}}
    </template>
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
      <div>{{ data.item.description}}</div>
    </template>
  </v-autocomplete>
```

and add following script:

```
methods: {
  filter (item, queryText, itemText) {
    if (queryText != null && item != null && item.description) {
      return item.description.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
    }
    return -1
  }
}
```